# Why file is not found in this simple web application

Tags: go, web-applications

I am working on Debian Stable Linux which is working very well. I have following directory structure for a simple Web application that takes 2 numbers from the user and returns the product of these 2 numbers:

```
.
├── ./main
├── ./main.go
└── ./static
    ├── ./static/favicon.ico
    ├── ./static/index.html
    └── ./static/style.css
```

I have following Go code:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
)
type ViewData struct {
    Product int
}
func multiplyHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err := r.ParseForm()
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Error parsing form", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    num1, err := strconv.Atoi(r.Form.Get("num1"))
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Invalid input for num1", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    num2, err := strconv.Atoi(r.Form.Get("num2"))
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Invalid input for num2", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    product := num1 * num2
    data := ViewData{
        Product: product,
    }
    tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles("index.html")
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Error parsing template", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    err = tmpl.Execute(w, data)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Error rendering template", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
}

func main() {
    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static"))))
    http.HandleFunc("/multiply", multiplyHandler)
    fmt.Println("Server listening on port 8080")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

Following is index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Multiplication Result</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Multiplication Result</h1>
    <p>Product: {{.Product}}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Following is style.css file:

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
}
h1 {
    color: #333;
}
p {
    color: #666;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

The go source code file main.go gets built without any warning or error messages.

I then run it with command: `./main`. Following is the message:

```
Server listening on port 8080
```

I then open the Firefox browser and put in url: http://localhost:8080 . However, the web page only shows:

```
404 page not found
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved?

Comment: It's `page not found` instead of `file not found`. Try this URL: `http://localhost:8080/multiply`.

Comment: Yes, but now the text on browser is:  `Invalid input for num1` There is no webpage coming.

Comment: Pass the query parameters like this: `http://localhost:8080/multiply?num1=5&num2=10`. And the path to the template is incorrect too. See my answer below.

Comment: With above url, I am getting on browser: `Error parsing template`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the changes to your code (the second change is not necessary, but it simplifies the code):

(Note: the changes are displayed in the `diff` format. But unfortunately, it's not syntax highlighted by stackoverflow)

```
 package main
 
 import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
 )
 
 type ViewData struct {
    Product int
 }
 
 func multiplyHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err := r.ParseForm()
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Error parsing form", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    num1, err := strconv.Atoi(r.Form.Get("num1"))
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Invalid input for num1", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    num2, err := strconv.Atoi(r.Form.Get("num2"))
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Invalid input for num2", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    product := num1 * num2
    data := ViewData{
        Product: product,
    }
-   tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles("index.html")
+   tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles("static/index.html")
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Error parsing template", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    err = tmpl.Execute(w, data)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Error rendering template", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
 }
 
 func main() {
-   http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static"))))
+   http.Handle("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(".")))
    http.HandleFunc("/multiply", multiplyHandler)
    fmt.Println("Server listening on port 8080")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
 }
```

Then open this URL in the browser (to provide the required parameters `num1` and `num2`):

```
http://localhost:8080/multiply?num1=5&num2=10
```

Comment: With this I am getting panic: `panic: http: multiple registrations for /static/`

Comment: It's display in the `diff` format. The line starts with `-` should be removed.